# WIFI dongle issues Mediatek MT7601U on Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic)

Tags: wireless, 18.04, ralink

Output of `sudo modprobe mt7601u && dmesg | grep mt76`:

```
201302052146____
[ 3823.291922] mt7601u 1-1:1.0: EEPROM ver:0c fae:00
[ 3823.461320] mt7601u 1-1:1.0: Error: RX urb failed:-71
[ 3823.461350] mt7601u 1-1:1.0: Error: MCU resp urb failed:-71
[ 3823.461355] mt7601u 1-1:1.0: Error: MCU resp evt:0 seq:5-4!
[ 3823.465673] mt7601u 1-1:1.0: Error: RX urb failed:-71
[ 3823.465920] mt7601u 1-1:1.0: Error: MCU resp urb failed:-71
[ 3823.465925] mt7601u 1-1:1.0: Error: MCU resp evt:0 seq:5-4!
[ 3823.469941] mt7601u 1-1:1.0: Error: RX urb failed:-71
[ 3823.470175] mt7601u 1-1:1.0: Error: MCU resp urb failed:-71
[ 3823.470180] mt7601u 1-1:1.0: Error: MCU resp evt:0 seq:5-4!
[ 3823.474197] mt7601u 1-1:1.0: Error: RX urb failed:-71
[ 3823.474423] mt7601u 1-1:1.0: Error: MCU resp urb failed:-71
[ 3823.474428] mt7601u 1-1:1.0: Error: MCU resp evt:0 seq:5-4!
[ 3823.478569] mt7601u 1-1:1.0: Error: RX urb failed:-71
[ 3823.478818] mt7601u 1-1:1.0: Error: MCU resp urb failed:-71
[ 3823.478823] mt7601u 1-1:1.0: Error: MCU resp evt:0 seq:5-4!
[ 3823.478827] mt7601u 1-1:1.0: Error: mt7601u_mcu_wait_resp timed out
[ 3823.683789] mt7601u 1-1:1.0: Vendor request req:07 off:0080 failed:-71
[ 3823.883701] mt7601u 1-1:1.0: Vendor request req:02 off:0080 failed:-71
[ 3824.083730] mt7601u 1-1:1.0: Vendor request req:02 off:0080 failed:-71
[ 3824.083775] mt7601u: probe of 1-1:1.0 failed with error -110
[ 3824.819458] mt7601u 1-1:1.0: ASIC revision: 76010001 MAC revision: 76010500
[ 3824.820953] mt7601u 1-1:1.0: Firmware Version: 0.1.00 Build: 7640 Build time: 201302052146____
```

Output of the Wireless Script:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 13 May 2019 12:56 BST +0100

Booted last: 13 May 2019 00:00 BST +0100

Script from: 22 Oct 2018 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.18.0-17-generic #18~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 15 15:27:12 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=1

##### desktop ###########################

ubuntu-wayland

##### lspci #############################

04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Onboard Ethernet [1458:e000]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

05:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Onboard Ethernet [1458:e000]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05ac:12a8 Apple, Inc. iPhone5/5C/5S/6
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 248a:ff0f  
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 048: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

##### secure boot #######################

'mokutil' is not installed (package "mokutil").

##### lsmod #############################

rt2800usb              32768  0
rt2x00usb              20480  1 rt2800usb
rt2800lib             114688  1 rt2800usb
rt2x00lib              53248  3 rt2800usb,rt2x00usb,rt2800lib
mac80211              802816  4 rt2x00lib,mt7601u,rt2x00usb,rt2800lib
cfg80211              667648  3 rt2x00lib,mt7601u,mac80211
mxm_wmi                16384  0
wmi                    24576  1 mxm_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

[/etc/network/interfaces]
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp4s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp4s0' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
3: enp5s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp5s0' [IF2]> brd <MAC address>
4: enp0s29f7u1c4i2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp0s29f7u1c4i2' [IF3]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 172.20.10.6/28 brd 172.20.10.15 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp0s29f7u1c4i2
       valid_lft 85243sec preferred_lft 85243sec
    inet6 2a01:4c8:c1b:e8d7:b129:e9a3:92ed:eb58/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 604509sec preferred_lft 85664sec
    inet6 2a01:4c8:c1b:e8d7:8d8d:4706:37ba:78a6/64 scope global mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::7833:f793:e40b:cd85/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

enp4s0    no wireless extensions.

enp5s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp0s29f7u1c4i2  no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

default via 172.20.10.1 dev enp0s29f7u1c4i2 proto dhcp metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s29f7u1c4i2 scope link metric 1000 
172.20.10.0/28 dev enp0s29f7u1c4i2 proto kernel scope link src 172.20.10.6 metric 100 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       696     1  0 12:34 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp0s29f7u1c4i2
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Apple Inc.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        iPhone
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         ipheth
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 --
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp0s29f7u1c4i2' [IF3]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-1/2-1:4.2/net/enp0s29f7u1c4i2
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp0s29f7u1c4i2
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 3
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       1279819e-26dd-362d-b88e-daa246078587
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         172.20.10.6/28
IP4.GATEWAY:                            172.20.10.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 172.20.10.1, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 172.20.10.0/28, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             172.20.10.1
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        network_number = 172.20.10.0
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        server_name = Jools
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        domain_name_servers = 172.20.10.1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       next_server = 172.20.10.1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       broadcast_address = 172.20.10.15
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 85536
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       routers = 172.20.10.1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       ip_address = 172.20.10.6
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       expiry = 1557833815
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 172.20.10.1
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.240
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         2a01:4c8:c1b:e8d7:b129:e9a3:92ed:eb58/64
IP6.ADDRESS[2]:                         2a01:4c8:c1b:e8d7:8d8d:4706:37ba:78a6/64
IP6.ADDRESS[3]:                         fe80::7833:f793:e40b:cd85/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            fe80::4f7:4c30:70a2:ec79
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 2a01:4c8:c1b:e8d7::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = ::/0, nh = fe80::4f7:4c30:70a2:ec79, mt = 100
IP6.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = ff00::/8, nh = ::, mt = 256, table=255
IP6.ROUTE[4]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256
IP6.ROUTE[5]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100
IP6.DNS[1]:                             fe80::4f7:4c30:70a2:ec79
DHCP6.OPTION[1]:                        requested_dhcp6_domain_search = 1
DHCP6.OPTION[2]:                        dhcp6_name_servers = fe80::4f7:4c30:70a2:ec79
DHCP6.OPTION[3]:                        dhcp6_server_id = 0:1:0:1:24:6c:13:93:22:db:70:8c:a3:64
DHCP6.OPTION[4]:                        requested_dhcp6_client_id = 1
DHCP6.OPTION[5]:                        requested_dhcp6_name_servers = 1
DHCP6.OPTION[6]:                        dhcp6_client_id = 0:4:53:a7:82:87:51:50:a6:9b:ef:25:87:8e:b1:43:44:93
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{3}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   1279819e-26dd-362d-b88e-daa246078587 | Wired connection 3

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp4s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Onboard Ethernet)
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp4s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:04:00.0/net/enp4s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp5s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Onboard Ethernet)
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp5s0' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:05:00.0/net/enp5s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:wwan

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com/

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-mac-addr-change-wifi]
match-device=driver:rtl8723bs,driver:rtl8189es,driver:r8188eu,driver:8188eu,driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
wifi.cloned-mac-address=preserve
ethernet.cloned-mac-address=preserve

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/London (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

enp4s0    no frequency information.

enp5s0    no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

enp0s29f7u1c4i2  no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

enp4s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp5s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp0s29f7u1c4i2  Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[rt2800usb]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.18.0-17-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ralink/rt2x00/rt2800usb.ko
license:        GPL
firmware:       rt2870.bin
description:    Ralink RT2800 USB Wireless LAN driver.
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
srcversion:     FEBC4C1F96FEAE2A7985E9A
depends:        rt2x00lib,rt2800lib,rt2x00usb
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           rt2800usb
vermagic:       4.18.0-17-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption. (bool)

[rt2x00usb]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.18.0-17-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ralink/rt2x00/rt2x00usb.ko
license:        GPL
description:    rt2x00 usb library
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
srcversion:     4783320285808F336F94F86
depends:        rt2x00lib,mac80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           rt2x00usb
vermagic:       4.18.0-17-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4

[rt2800lib]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.18.0-17-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ralink/rt2x00/rt2800lib.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Ralink RT2800 library
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com, Bartlomiej Zolnierkiewicz
srcversion:     966CF51FCABF548A597F127
depends:        rt2x00lib,mac80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           rt2800lib
vermagic:       4.18.0-17-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4

[rt2x00lib]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.18.0-17-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ralink/rt2x00/rt2x00lib.ko
license:        GPL
description:    rt2x00 library
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
srcversion:     E9726B139222EDB02105054
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           rt2x00lib
vermagic:       4.18.0-17-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.18.0-17-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     C5D73328CD704BB6E363074
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           mac80211
vermagic:       4.18.0-17-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.18.0-17-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     BFB309EF7C6C321F605D36E
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       4.18.0-17-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[rt2800usb]
nohwcrypt: N

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

rt2800usb
rt2800usb

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: This chipset should be natively supported starting with kernel 4.19.

Comment: What is the response to the terminal command: sudo modprobe mt7601u && dmesg | grep mt76`? Please edit your question to show the result. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chilli555 done. That code sample repeated itself for about thirty times or more. Thanks for help so far

Comment: @Kulfy I was using the Ctrl+K command. I edited it to use the three apostrophes though and it worked then.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I updated the kernel to 4.19 and still nothing. I even tried the very latest kernel with no positive results

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Install **wpasupplicant** will solve the problem.

```
$ sudo apt install -y wpasupplicant
$ sudo netplan apply
```

> I don't know why... but works

- OS: 19.10
- USB WIFI: Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter

`/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`:

```
network:
    ethernets:
      enp3s0:
        dhcp4: true
        optional: true
    wifis:
      wlxe84e0634d6f5:
        dhcp4: true
        optional: true
        access-points:
          "ssid":
            password: "wifi_password"
    version: 2
```